# GA4 Migration: error message "Google Analytics 4 (GA4) not receiving events from Universal Analytics (UA)"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to import existing goals from UA to GA4. It says I have 3 eligible goals for migration.
[A screenshot of the migration tool here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c4lk.png)

However, when I clicked the Import conversions button, the popup shows up saying "Google Analytics 4 (GA4) not receiving events from Universal Analytics (UA)".
[A screenshot of the error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHBRY.png)

Could someone help me with setting these up please?

We use GTM. When I clicked the link in the popup, it brings me here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10762548?hl=en&utm_id=ad#gtm&zippy=%2Cin-this-article

1. I created the GA4 configuration tag with Initiation - all page trigger
2. I did Option 2 and created a new Google Analytics 4 Event tag in Tag Manager for Added to Cart event.
3. I don't know what to do with Completed Purchase and Started Checkout event. Do I have to create a new Event tag in Tag Manager for these as well? How do I do that?